# sum zeros and ones by another vector in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following data array **m**:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1],[0],[1],[0],[0]]
b = [[1],[0],[1],[0],[0]]
c = d = [[1],[0],[1],[0],[0]]
m = np.hstack((a,b,c,d))
m
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

I have the following vector **prior**

```
prior = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
```

I now want to create a new vector of length 5, where each row of **m** is summed according to this scheme

if 1 then add 1/prior

if 0 then add 0.1*1/prior

so for the first row in **m** we would get

```
(1/0.1)+(0.1*1/0.2)+(1/0.3)+(1/0.4) = 16.33
```

the second row is

```
(0.1*1/0.1)+(0.1*1/0.2)+(0.1*1/0.3)+(0.1*1/0.4) = 2.083
```

**m** should be the basis and numpy may be used (perhaps .sum(axis=1)) ?

**UPDATE** :

I'm also interested in a solution where **m** can take more than two different integers. For example I want a third rule for `m==2` and add these values 0.2*1/prior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using `numpy` I would recommend `numpy.where` and `numpy.sum`. Note that this works only if you make `prior` a `numpy.array`.

```
p = np.asarray(prior)

np.sum(np.where(m,1./p,0.1/p),axis=1)
# array([ 16.33333333,   2.08333333,  20.83333333,   2.08333333,   6.58333333])
```

**Note**

`np.where` usually expects an array of `bools`. However, when you give a list of `integers` the number `0` is interpreted as a `False` and everything else as a `True`

**Update**

If you want to add a third rule for the occurrence of `2` in `m` I would use `np.choose` instead of `np.where`. If you want to have `0.2/p` for the occurrence of `2` you can do

```
p = np.asarray(prior)
p_vec = np.vstack((0.1/p,1./p,0.2/p))
np.choose(m,p_vec).sum(axis=1)
```

The idea is to create first a list `p_vec` which contains `0.1/p`,`1./p` and `0.2/p`. The command `np.choose` picks then the corresponding entity out of the list depending on `m`.

This can easily extended for integers `3,4,...` just add the corresponding data to `p_vec`.

Comment: Except it'd be better if one is little more explicit in `where(m==1, 1./prior, 0.1/prior)`

Comment: Well ... one could do also `m.astype(np.bool)` but eventually all gives the same ...

Comment: thanks, very nice. Do you have a simple numpy solution for when I have three different integers (0,1,2) in m and want to add 0.2/p for these cases?

Comment: @spore234 : You mean for `0` and `1` the same rule as before and for `2` this new rule?

Comment: @plonser exactly, just add a third rule for the `2`s

Answer (score 3):

**Approach #1:** Vectorized approach with [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
# Calculate the reciprocal of prior as a numpy array
prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)

# Mask of ones (1s) in array, m
mask = m==1

# Use the mask for m==1 and otherwise with proper scales: prior_reci
# and 0.1*prior_reci respectively and sum them up along the rows
out = (mask*prior_reci + ~mask*(0.1*prior_reci)).sum(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [58]: m
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [59]: prior
Out[59]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

In [60]: prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)
    ...: mask = m==1
    ...: 

In [61]: (mask*prior_reci + ~mask*(0.1*prior_reci)).sum(1)
Out[61]: array([ 16.33333333,   2.08333333,  20.83333333,   2.08333333,   6.58333333])
```

---

**Approach #2:** Using [`matrix-multiplication with np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
# Calculate the reciprocal of prior as a numpy array
prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)

# Sum along rows for m==1 with scaling of prior_reci per row
# would be equivalent to np.dot(m,prior_reci).
# Similarly for m!=1, it would be np.dot(1-m,0.1*prior_reci) 
# i.e. with the new scaling 0.1*prior_reci. 
# Finally we need to combine them up with summation.
out = np.dot(m,prior_reci) + np.dot(1-m,0.1*prior_reci)
```

Sample run -

```
In [77]: m
Out[77]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [78]: prior
Out[78]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

In [79]: prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)

In [80]: np.dot(m,prior_reci) + np.dot(1-m,0.1*prior_reci)
Out[80]: array([ 16.33333333,   2.08333333,  20.83333333,   2.08333333,   6.58333333])
```

---

**Runtime tests** to compare the earlier listed two approaches -

```
In [102]: # Parameters
     ...: H = 1000
     ...: W = 1000
     ...: 
     ...: # Create inputs
     ...: m = np.random.randint(0,2,(H,W))
     ...: prior = np.random.rand(W).tolist()
     ...: 

In [103]: %%timeit
     ...: prior_reci1 = 1/np.asarray(prior)
     ...: mask = m==1
     ...: out1 = (mask*prior_reci1 + ~mask*(0.1*prior_reci1)).sum(1)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

In [104]: %%timeit
     ...: prior_reci2 = 1/np.asarray(prior)
     ...: out2 = np.dot(m,prior_reci2) + np.dot(1-m,0.1*prior_reci2)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6 ms per loop
```

---

**Generic solution** to handle multiple conditional checks could be solved in a vectorized manner with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
# Define scalars that are to be matched against input 2D array, m
matches = [0,1,2,3,4] # Edit this to accomodate more matching conditions

# Define multiplying factors for the reciprocal version of prior
prior_multfactors = [0.1,1,0.2,0.3,0.4] # Edit this corresponding to matches 
                                  # for different multiplying factors

# Thus, for the given matches and prior_multfactors, it means:
# when m==0, then do: 0.1/prior
# when m==1, then do: 1/prior
# when m==2, then do: 0.2/prior
# when m==3, then do: 0.3/prior
# when m==4, then do: 0.4/prior

# Define prior list
prior = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]

# Calculate the reciprocal of prior as a numpy array
prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)

# Mask for every element of m satisfying or not 
# all the matches to produce a 3D array mask
mask = m==np.asarray(matches)[:,None,None]

# Get scaling factors for each matches across each prior_reci value
scales = np.asarray(prior_multfactors)[:,None]*prior_reci

# Einsum-mation to give sum across rows corresponding to all matches
out = np.einsum('ijk,ik->j',mask,scales)
```

Sample run -

```
In [203]: m
Out[203]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 2, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 2, 0]])

In [204]: matches, prior_multfactors
Out[204]: ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0.1, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

In [205]: prior
Out[205]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

In [206]: prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)
     ...: mask = m==np.asarray(matches)[:,None,None]
     ...: scales = np.asarray(prior_multfactors)[:,None]*prior_reci
     ...: 

In [207]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->j',mask,scales)
Out[207]: array([ 16.33333333,   2.08333333,   8.5       ,   2.08333333,   3.91666667])
```

Comment: @spore234 It seems you want to calculate for m==2 and so on cases? Maybe edit the question with these new requirements and same input-output?

Comment: I extended the question

Answer (score 1):

Not saying it's better than Divikar's, just alternative:

```
prior_reci = 1/np.asarray(prior)
(a * prior_reci + (1 - a)*prior_reci/10).sum(axis=1)
```